# ECDH Shared secret derived from OpenSSL and BouncyCastle are not always the same although constants and domain parameters are the same for both

Tags: ios, openssl, bouncycastle, elliptic-curve

I'm trying to implement AES cryptography between an iOS app and a java servlet. Java servlet uses BouncyCastle library while iOS app uses OpenSSL. Although I've used same public/private key pair and domain parameters for both side, shared secret generated by OpenSSL sometimes differs from what generates by BouncyCastle on server - side.

The procedure is as follows;

1. a public/private key pair generated in server with specified domain
   parameters (say `server_public_key`, `server_private_key`)
2. `server_public_key` is embedded in iOS app in form of an `EC_POINT` X
   and Y
3. at run-time iOS app generates its own public/private key pair (say
   `client_key_curve` which is an `EC_KEY`), and
4. then loads `server_public_key` and calculates shared secret
   (`key_agreement`) based on server_public_key and client_key_curve, and
5. then `client_public_key` (extracted from `client_key_curve`) as well as
   a ciphered message which is encrypted symmetrically using the
   derived shared secret (`key_agreement`) are sent to server
6. in server - side, shared secret again is calculated using
   `client_public_key` and server ECDH parameters which are the same as
   client side, and
7. then ciphered message decrypted using computed `key_agreement`

BUT the decrypted messages are not always the same as the client sent messages.

Since I've also developed an Android app which uses the same procedure but employs BouncyCastle for cryptography therefore I suspect the correctness of implemented code using OpenSSL, so the code is revealed here for others to help resolving the issue. What I've implemented to calculate the shared secret is as follows

```
- (void)calculateSharedSecret
{
    BN_CTX* bn_ctx;

    EC_KEY*     client_key_curve = NULL;
    EC_KEY*     server_key_curve = NULL;
    EC_GROUP*   client_key_group = NULL;
    EC_GROUP*   server_key_group = NULL;
    EC_POINT*   client_publicKey = NULL;
    EC_POINT*   server_publicKey = NULL;
    BIGNUM*     client_privatKey = NULL;

    BIGNUM* client_publicK_x = NULL;
    BIGNUM* client_publicK_y = NULL;
    BIGNUM* server_publicK_x = NULL;
    BIGNUM* server_publicK_y = NULL;

    NSException *p = [NSException exceptionWithName:@"" reason:@"" userInfo:nil];

    bn_ctx = BN_CTX_new();
    BN_CTX_start(bn_ctx);

    client_publicK_x = BN_CTX_get(bn_ctx);
    client_publicK_y = BN_CTX_get(bn_ctx);
    client_privatKey = BN_CTX_get(bn_ctx);
    server_publicK_x = BN_CTX_get(bn_ctx);
    server_publicK_y = BN_CTX_get(bn_ctx);

    // client

    if ((client_key_curve = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_X9_62_prime256v1)) == NULL)
        @throw p;

    if ((client_key_group = (EC_GROUP *)EC_KEY_get0_group(client_key_curve)) == NULL)
        @throw p;

    if (EC_KEY_generate_key(client_key_curve) != 1)
        @throw p;

    if ((client_publicKey = (EC_POINT *)EC_KEY_get0_public_key(client_key_curve)) == NULL)
        @throw p;

    if (EC_KEY_check_key(client_key_curve) != 1)
        @throw p;

    client_privatKey = (BIGNUM *)EC_KEY_get0_private_key(client_key_curve);

    char *client_public_key = EC_POINT_point2hex(client_key_group, client_publicKey, POINT_CONVERSION_COMPRESSED, bn_ctx);
    char *client_privat_key = BN_bn2hex(client_privatKey);

    _clientPublicKey = [NSString stringWithCString:client_public_key encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // server

    NSArray* lines = [self loadServerPublicKeyXY];

    NSString *public_str_x = [lines objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *public_str_y = [lines objectAtIndex:1];

    BN_dec2bn(&server_publicK_x, [public_str_x UTF8String]);
    BN_dec2bn(&server_publicK_y, [public_str_y UTF8String]);

    if ((server_key_curve = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_X9_62_prime256v1)) == NULL)
        @throw p;

    if ((server_key_group = (EC_GROUP *)EC_KEY_get0_group(server_key_curve)) == NULL)
        @throw p;

    if (EC_KEY_generate_key(server_key_curve) != 1)
        @throw p;

    if ((server_publicKey = EC_POINT_new(server_key_group)) == NULL)
        @throw p;

    if (EC_POINT_set_affine_coordinates_GFp(server_key_group, server_publicKey, server_publicK_x, server_publicK_y, bn_ctx) != 1)
        @throw p;

    if (EC_KEY_check_key(server_key_curve) != 1)
        @throw p;

    unsigned char *key_agreement = NULL;
    key_agreement = (unsigned char *)OPENSSL_malloc(SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH);
    if (ECDH_compute_key(key_agreement, SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH, server_publicKey, client_key_curve, KDF1_SHA1) == 0)
        @throw p;
    _symmetricKey = [NSData dataWithBytes:key_agreement length:16];
}
```

and

```
void *KDF1_SHA1(const void *input, size_t inlen, void *output, size_t *outlen)
{
    if (*outlen < SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH)
        return NULL;
    else
        *outlen = SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH;
    return SHA1(input, inlen, output);
}
```

`_clientPublicKey` and `_symmetricKey` are declared at class level

The same curve (named prime256v1 or secp256r1) is used on both side but the results are not always the same.

**EDIT 1**:
In response to @PeterDettman, I’ve published server – side code for more clarification

```
public byte[] generateAESSymmetricKey(byte[] client_public_key_hex) throws InvalidRequest{
    try {
        // ECDH Private Key as well as other prime256v1 params was generated by Java "keytool" and stored in a JKS file
        KeyStore keyStore = ...;
        PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey("keyAlias", "keyStorePassword".toCharArray());
        ECPrivateKeyParameters ecdhPrivateKeyParameters = (ECPrivateKeyParameters) (PrivateKeyFactory.createKey(privateKey.getEncoded()));

        ECCurve ecCurve = ecdhPrivateKeyParameters.getParameters().getCurve();
        ECDomainParameters ecDomainParameters = ecdhPrivateKeyParameters.getParameters();
        ECPublicKeyParameters client_public_key = new ECPublicKeyParameters(ecCurve.decodePoint(client_public_key_hex), ecDomainParameters);

        BasicAgreement agree = new ECDHBasicAgreement();
        agree.init(ecdhPrivateKeyParameters);
        byte[] keyAgreement = agree.calculateAgreement(client_public_key).toByteArray();

        SHA1Digest sha1Digest = new SHA1Digest();
        sha1Digest.update(keyAgreement, 0, keyAgreement.length);
        byte hashKeyAgreement[] = new byte[sha1Digest.getDigestSize()];
        sha1Digest.doFinal(hashKeyAgreement, 0);

        byte[] server_calculatd_symmetric_key = new byte[16];
        System.arraycopy(hashKeyAgreement, 0, server_calculatd_symmetric_key, 0, server_calculatd_symmetric_key.length);
        return server_calculatd_symmetric_key;
    } catch (Throwable ignored) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

where `client_public_key_hex` is `client_public_key` that is converted to an array of byte. The expected result is that `server_calculatd_symmetric_key` equals `symmetricKey` for all the time. BUT they are not always the same.

**EDIT 2**:
As a feedback to @PeterDettman answer, I made some changes to reflect his suggestion and although rate of inequality reduces, generated key agreements (shared secret) on either side are not still equal in all cases.

It is possible to reproduce one of inequality case with following data

- Public key :
  **02E05C058C3DF6E8D63791660D9C5EA98B5A0822AB93339B0B8815322131119C4C**
- Privat key :
  **062E8AC930BD6009CF929E51B37432498075D21C335BD00086BF68CE09933ACA**
- Generated Shared Secret by OpenSSL : **51d027264f8540e5d0fde70000000000**
- Generated Shared Secret by BouncyCastle :
  **51d027264f8540e5d0fde700e5db0fab**

So is there any mistake in the implemented code or procedure?

Thanks

Comment: Is the shared secret being calculated the same on both sides?

Comment: @PeterDettman : Sometimes calculated Shared Secret on both sides are equal and sometimes not (I'd better say most of the time they are not equal). As soon as I change the type of EC curve from **prime256v1 – secp256r1** to **prime192v1** the rate of inequality of calculated shared secret reduces. I mean they are more likely to be equal on **prime192v1** curve and I have no idea why it is so.

Comment: Perhaps you could show the servlet code that uses BouncyCastle, particularly the part that takes the raw agreement value and derives the symmetric key from it.

Comment: @PeterDettman, servlet code is now added to the question, Would you please let me know where I may make mistake?

Comment: After EDIT 2, I am unable to reproduce that data. Using prime256v1 and the keys given, my Java code gives a value for keyAgreement of "8ef56ec2a6e96e11c5ce5a72a6b41673405be87b30a70b6fc549bab7b3c7691d". Perhaps you gave the wrong keys.

Comment: In any case, if the shared secrets you listed are prior to SHA-1 for some other key (please be clearer what values you are reporting), then the 4 trailing zero bytes in the OpenSSL version would seem most likely to be incorrect. I suspect there is something wrong with your KDF1_SHA1 method, but it's still not obvious that you are reporting the output from the key agreement correctly. When KDF1_SHA1 is called, what are the first 'inlen' bytes of 'input'?

Comment: Finally, the fact that your OpenSSL shared secret appears to stop being correct as soon as a 00 byte appears indicates something in your code might be treating a 00 byte as an end-of-string. Are you using strcpy instead of memcpy somewhere?

Comment: Sorry! I had not seen your comment here. I'll include java side KeyAgreement generation code for more clarification

Comment: As you've pointed out, having a trailing of zeros is strange and I do not know why. I've not used any memory copy function. The iOS side code is as just as I've published

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a problem in the server code, in the way that the ECDH agreement value is converted to bytes:

```
byte[] keyAgreement = agree.calculateAgreement(client_public_key).toByteArray();
```

Try this instead:

```
BigInteger agreementValue = agree.calculateAgreement(client_public_key);
byte[] keyAgreement = BigIntegers.asUnsignedByteArray(agree.getFieldSize(), agreementValue);
```

This will ensure a fixed-size byte array as output, which is a requirement for converting EC field elements to octet strings (search "Field Element to Octet String Conversion Primitive" for more details).

I recommend you ignore the SHA1 key derivation part until you can get that Java keyAgreement byte array to exactly match the input to your KDF1_SHA1 function.

Comment: Dear @PeterDettman, I followed your suggestion and the feedback was appended to the question. Would you please check it?

Comment: In fact I ignored applying SHA on computed key agreement on both side according to your suggestion however sometimes they are completely different

Comment: Please report what *input* is being sent to KDF1_SHA1 in the iOS app, and the corresponding value of keyAgreement on the Java side.

Comment: appreciation in advance for your attention, as I said, I've ignored applying `SHA1` on `key_agreement` output of `ECDH_compute_key`. I mean I just passed `NULL` instead of `KDF1_SHA1` to `ECDH_compute_key` in iOS side. At the same time I ignored applying SHA on java side. Now row key agreement on both side are sometimes identical and sometimes not, such as the case that I've reported. Please have a look at the question.